# In WebStorm, where is the Repository URL history stored?

Tags: version-control, configuration, dialog, webstorm

In WebStorm 8, when you want to create a local clone of a Github repository, you get this dialog:

[image: Webstorm Dialog for Cloning Github Repository]

My `Vcs Repository URL` combobox is crammed with a long history of URLs. Moreover, the list is sorted alphabetically, and the initial URL in the field (not shown in the screenshot) belongs to a repository I don't use anymore, from another company whose name happens to start with 'A'.

**Question:** Where is this list stored and/or how can I edit it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combobox contains 2 groups of entries separated by '---'. The entries shown above the separator are your repositories found on github. This information is retrieved from server and is not stored locally anywhere. Entries shown below the separator come from your URLs history. History is stored in $WebStorm config dir/options/vcs.xml and can be removed by editing this file. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108 for information about configuration directories location (it's OS-specific)

Comment: Hm. Almost, but not exactly. Near the end of the combobox list, there is a separator '----------' with more entries following. `vcs.xml` is the file with those entries. The vast majority appearing before the separator must be stored elsewhere. (I'm more confused now than I was before.)

Comment: it's really strange... vcs.config is the only file this stuff is written to. At lease I'm not aware of anything else. Also, haven't seen any separators. Please can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: sorry, didn't notice that this is about github, not git... Repositories shown above the separator are your repositories found on github. This information is retrieved from server and is not stored locally anywhere - it's not a history. Those shown below the separator are stored in vcs.xml - this is a history that can be deleted

Comment: I see, thanks! If you put this information in your answer, I'll accept it. ----- A side-question: Is that, by any chance, the only difference between the 'Git' and 'Github' clone dialogs? Can I just use the 'Git' dialog with ultimately the same result?